# iOS8 UITableViewCell with ImageView autolayout cell stretch

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout

I am trying to implement **AutoLayout** on a tableview in iOS 8 with **Swift** and have it so the cell that holds an image automatically enlarges to fit the image in the correct aspect ratio(aspect fit). I can get it so if I select an image from the image picker and it will display the picture properly. But if I then open the app and expect the image to show the same, it shows are a tiny square. I know it's something to do with my constraints not being set right but I can figure out where the issue lies. The console is complaining about the constraints as well.  See the pictures and the code I'm using.

Link to what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jSBV.png

Link to the constraints setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5xCR.png

And the code I use to control the image aspect:

```
func showImage(image: UIImage) {
    let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height

    aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)

    imageView.image = image
    imageView.hidden = false
    addPhotoLabel.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your side edge constraints are what's messing it up.
Remove those, and instead apply an aspect ratio constraint. if you force margins on one axis (top/bottom OR left/right), it will scale the image proportionally to fit.

Comment: Would i keep the constraint code? I tried to remove the left and right constraints and added the aspect ratio constraint but i cant get them to turn blue.

Comment: I avoid using code constraints when possible. You can manipulate IB constraints pretty easily by creating outlets in your code. 

One thing to note though, is that the `UIImageView` isn't automatically 'shrink-wrapped' to the size of the image. Using the size of the image you can create your constraints in code based on the actual aspect ratio of the image. Use the `size` property of your UIImage to determine the aspect ratio.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example of that? I'm fairly new to this.. Thanks!

Comment: You actually are already doing it with `aspect`. I misread that and thought it said `UIImageView`..

In the tableView code, you should modify `heightForCellAtIndexPath:` to set your cell height to the size you want - either the full size of the image, or some reasonable maximum. You can size your cell based on the aspect ratio and the width of the cell, which shouldn't ever change. Your heigh would end up being the MIN of image height, or the proportional figure to make the width=cell width.

It's easier to describe it, since I can't add code blocks in here, but hopefully that gets you started